# A construction of the Hilbert-Chow morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm studying the Hilbert scheme of points on a surface and I've just defined the set-theoretic Hilbert-Chow morphism. I would like to know if someone knows a reference to study the scheme-theoretic construction of the Hilbert-Chow morphism.
I was suggested to search an article of Lehn, but all his articles, I've seen, never talk about that.
Thank you!

Comment: One source is 'Local properties and Hilbert schemes of points' by Fantechi and Göttsche, in the volume 'Fundamental Algebraic Geometry' for the 2003 Trieste School, published by AMS.

Comment: Matthieu's suggestion is excellent.  Another reference is Section I.6 of Koll'ar's "Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties".

Comment: See Amnon Neeman, *Zero cycles in $P^n$*, Adv. Math. **89** (1991), no. 2, 217–227. There is also a discussion in Section 4.3 of David Rydh's paper *Hilbert and Chow schemes, symmetric powers and divided powers*, http://www.math.kth.se/~dary/thesis/thesis-paperIII.pdf